# I am having trouble connecting to another machine via a shared network switch

Tags: windows, ip

so I am a complete newb to this, so hope this is the right place for help. So I have a local network of a few different machines that are all locally connected to a network switch. I use one specific machine to check on the others and connect to them if need be. I recently added new machine and connected it to the local network switch. However I cannot connect to this new machine nor can I ping it. The network ID of the new machine is different to ones that are already on the network switch. My question is what do I need to modify/change to be able to connect to this new machine. I checked that actual physically connection and it has continuity.

Comment: If the net ID (that part of the IP address that specifies the network) is different, you won't be able to connect without routing.  How are IP addresses assigned?  And, I guess, this is IPv4, right?

Comment: If the answer below didn't help you, please give us more information, either here in the comments or preferably, by editing your question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've made a couple of assumptions in this answer, namely that you're using IPv4 and that by network ID you mean the left part of the IP address, the part marked by ones in the netmask.

To enable direct communication through the switch, without routing, all devices on the switch must have the same network ID and be different only in the host part of the address.  The host part must be unique, *i.e.* no duplicates.

If addresses are assigned by a properly-configured DHCP server, things ought to "just work."  If they're manually assigned, you will need to correct that one.  (And, if they're assigned by DHCP, you have a DHCP configuration problem.)

**Added:** if the address on the problem machine looks like  169.254.x.x, it is a dynamically configured link-local address.  That means the machine is looking for but not finding a DHCP server, and so used an address from a special range reserved to allow hosts to configure themselves.  If that's the case and DHCP is in use, the new host can't reach the DHCP server for some reason, or the problem host was not configured to use DHCP.  The latter is unlikely if it's a Microsoft operating system.  If you're not using DHCP, it means the host's IP address was not configured before the machine was connected to the network.

**Another addition:** Computers on a local network identify each other by sending ARP (address resolution protocol) requests.  The ARP protocol returns a MAC (medium access control) address which is subsequently used for communication.  *However,* ARP requests are generated only for the hosts's own network/subnet.  Packets for other requests are sent to a gateway router, in the most common case to the default gateway.  Your router by default probably won't "route back" to local addresses, and so either tries to forward the packet to the wide-area network or drops it entirely.

You *could* upgrade to a switch that supports VLANs, modify your router's configuration, or add routing tables to the local hosts, but the easiest solution is to fix the IP address of the failing host to be within the local network unless there's a  reason why that's impossible.